How to run all the tests across all spec files on single browser instance?
In our scenario, all the tests across different spec file should run on one single browser context.I should open a browser and run all the test cases on the same browser session.How to achieve this using playwright,I am ok to comprimize on test isolation.
I tried by sharing the browser context across the tests but some how it did not worked out well.

Please share a [mcve] of your attempt. Thanks.

Yes please share the code of what you have tried so far.Help us in helping you.

Let's say I have three spec files as admin.spec.ts,books.spec.ts and loans.spec.ts.
when we use page fixures,each test will run on sepearate browser context,which is dedicated to that test.
My need is,all the tests should run only on one browser.
for example, the browser should launch in admin.spec.ts and all other spec file tests should use the same browser.
